# In the Commonwealth realms, who succeeds when a King dies leaving a daughter and a son in-utero?

Tags: united-kingdom, head-of-state

When Queen Elizabeth II became Queen on the death of her father, she was only able to do so because she had no brothers. (Otherwise, her eldest brother would have become King, under rules still in place today.)

What if, on that event, her mother happened to be pregnant with a boy? Would that boy be the King?

Possible follow-up question: What if the pregnancy is so new that the gender is unknown?

(I'm specifically interested in what happens under today's laws. I'm using Elizabeth II as an illustrative example. I don't think the laws have changed since then but I'm clarifying here in case they have.)

Comment: then her mother becomes the queen?

Comment: "I don't think the laws have changed"...except that [they have changed](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2013/20/contents). Nowadays, in the UK (and Commonwealth Realms), the eldest child becomes monarch, regardless of gender.

Comment: Still an interesting question though!

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff I'd make that an answer. Link to the CGP Grey video too.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea the rules had changed. I agree, you should make that an answer.

Comment: Now I'm curious what would have happened before this new law was passed.

Comment: Traditionally the daughter would have the wife of the king killed so that her brother could not challenge her claim to the throne.

Comment: @Jorel - Only if the wife of the king was eligible to be queen.  IE the wife was already a princess by birthright when she married the King.  Had Princess Diana lived and Charles became King she would have remained a princess because she was not of royal blood.

Comment: @Chad: that's not true; the current [Queen's mother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Elizabeth_The_Queen_Mother) had the title Queen, and she was not of royal blood either. Specifically, "[All female consorts have had the right to be and have been styled as queens consort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_British_consorts)".

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff - Consort != Queen/King as you see the consorts retain the title of princess or prince that they were bestowed upon marriage to the royal heir.  An interesting question might be what would happen to the royal line if Charles were to divorce and remarry someone eligible to be titled queen and then produce offspring from that marriage.  I think that the current Prince Harry might fall in place behind that offspring.

Comment: Interestingly a somewhat simliar case is regulated in german [inheritance law](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__1923.html): You have to be alive to be able to inherit - and those who are already sired are considered to be alive before the case of succession.

Comment: @Chad - ah, I see; you're talking about actually _being_ Queen, rather than merely having the _title_ "Queen". In that case, is it not the case that the wife of the late King would only become Queen if she was next in the line of succession, which could only happen if she was the late King's sister and had neither children nor older siblings -- which unless we're talking about Game of Thrones, seems quite unlikely nowadays... :-)

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff - There is no difference  If you have the title of Queen you are queen.  But Queen Consort is not the same title as Queen any more than Duke is the same as Archduke.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because most monarchies today including Britain have "fully cognate successions" that allow the oldest CHILD to inherit, whether daughter or son.

Comment: @TomAu What?  this question appears off topic because you know the answer to it?

Comment: @SamIam: If "I know the answer" to a question because it is "general reference," most SE sites would close it for that reason. If Sweden, England, and a bunch of other countries went "co-ed" in the past 35 years, leaving this question valid for only e.g. Nepal, then it would probably be "too localized." And the OP didn't realize that his example is now moot because England recently changed its law.

Comment: I did a quick Google search, and the first thing I read was: "[Succession to the British throne is governed both by common law and statute. Under common law the crown is inherited by male-preference cognatic primogeniture. In other words, succession passes first to an individual's sons, in order of birth, and subsequently to daughters, again in order of birth.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succession_to_the_British_throne)"  If what you just said about British successions is true, than you have information contrary to the most available reference, making this not a reference question.

Comment: @SamIam: OK, I retracted the close vote.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff: "except that they have changed." This is incorrect. The law has not changed yet in ANY Commonwealth realm. The UK act you cited has not come into force and does not come into force until the government decides to, which it announced it won't happen until legislation is passed in all Commonwealth realms (which has not happened; e.g. Australia still has not passed the legislation).

Comment: @TomAu The question can easily be extended to monarchies with “fully cognate succession”. What if the queen is pregnant with her first child? Could one of the king's younger siblings or their issue succeed him or do they have to yield to the unborn child?

Comment: @user102008: UPDATE: the provisions of the act were [brought into force on 26 March 2015](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2015/894/made).

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff: Yes, that's right. (Although there are pending constitutional challenges in Canada.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As multiple comments have mentioned, the laws governing succession in the Commonwealth are currently changing from male-preference primogeniture to absolute primogeniture.

In either case, though, a foetus not yet born has no rights under the law of the UK, and as such would have no claim to the throne, as it would have no claim to inheritance from its father's estate on his death.

Thus, if a monarch died under male-preference primogeniture the eldest living son at the time of death would become the new monarch; for lack of sons, the eldest daughter.

Expanding to absolute primogeniture, on the death of a monarch with no living descendants but with a pregnant queen-consort, he would be succeeded by his eldest sibling (or their descendants) as he has no living descendants in the eyes of the law.

Comment: (+1) Interestingly, France does not have this problem anymore but in civil matters, it still applies the [*Infans conceptur pro nato* principle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infans_conceptus_pro_nato_habetur_quoties_de_commodis_ejus_agitur). It seems the tradition in the UK is quite different.

Comment: @Relaxed France is a Civil Law country, not a Common Law country.

Comment: @nick012000 Yes, obviously but I guess I still thought it was interesting to note the difference as I wouldn't necessarily expect that to matter directly to something like the succession of of monarch. Civil codes, etc. developed much later.

Comment: I'm not clear on British rules but [Alfonso XIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfonso_XIII) became King of Spain despite being born after his father's death - his mother served as regent. (The only posthumous births in England/UK to take to the throne did it at the head of armies and a long time ago: Henry VII and William III.)

Answer (score 7):

As the law is now, an elder daughter takes precedence over a younger son, so there is no way way for an unborn child to acquire the throne in preference over someone already born.

However, Parliament has the freedom to vary this. The [Regency Act 1830](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regency_Act_1830) was introduced to cater for possible problems in the succession after the death of William IV. His heir presumptive was Princess Victoria of Kent, who became Queen Victoria when William died in 1837, Victoria having reached 18 and thus not requiring a regent.

The act specifically provided that if William's wife, Queen Adelaide, was pregnant at the time of William's death, that child would succeed to the throne on birth. If the child had died as an infant, Victoria would presumably have succeeded to the throne a second time. Fortunately, none of these things happened.